# getting data from ibm bluemix into python code

Tags: python, node.js, ibm-cloud, device, iot

I need code for getting data from bluemix which is sent by this code

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import dht11
import time
import datetime
import ibmiotf.device

# initialize GPIO
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.cleanup()

1
client.connect()



# read data using pin GPIO4
instance = dht11.DHT11(pin=4)

while True:
    result = instance.read()
    if result.is_valid():
        print("Last valid input: " + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
        temp=(" %d C" % result.temperature)
        print("temperature:" +temp)
        humid=("%d %%" % result.humidity)
    print("Humidity:" +humid)
       # print("Temperature: %d C" % result.temperature)
       # print("Humidity: %d %%" % result.humidity)
        print("Data is published into the cloued")
        Data={'Temperature' :temp, 'Humidity' :humid }
        client.publishEvent("status", "json", Data)

    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Please describe what you have achieved and tell us more about problem. This question requires editing.

Comment: from that code I sent data to bluemix i.e. {"temp":"34 c","humidity":"35"}. so now I want to retrieve that same data from iot device in bluemix to my python code.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Unfortunately your question does not meet the quality criteria and is likely to be closed.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use NodeRed to add some node(insert, function, iotout) to publish the data to iot platform(publish it as device type) into a topic then in the PI with pyhton subscribe to that topic as an application... that should work just fine. All the connection/publish/subscribing/topics details can be found here:
https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/index.html

Comment: I need only subscription code to the mentioned code

Answer (score 0):

You connect as a device -> `import ibmiotf.device`.  A device can send **events** and receive **commands**. It can't receive **events**.  To do this you need to connect as an application.  You will `import ibmiotf.application` and have something like:

```
options = ibmiotf.application.ParseConfigFile(configFilePath)
appClient = ibmiotf.application.Client(options)

appClient.connect()
appClient.subscribeToDeviceEvents()
```

The config file should be like:

```
[application]
org=orgId
id=myApplication
auth-method=apikey
auth-key=key
auth-token=token
```

Where the auth-key/auth-token comes from the Apps part of your platform. You'll have to generate a set to connect as an application.  The auth-method should be left as apikey.

That will list every event that arrives to your platform.  You can make it more granular.  See the [api guide](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/applications/libraries/python.html#subscribe_device_events) which also references a sample app on [github](https://github.com/ibm-watson-iot/iot-python/blob/master/samples/simpleApp/simpleApp.py).

Comment: that's fine, but how can I get that details back into python and displayed on console

Comment: Have you even tried it?  You will need to put more effort into your questions or you will find them closed.  You don't seem to have put any effort into this!

Comment: I tried, but it will provide the date, device id, device type like that details but, what I need is json data which is stored by above program...

Comment: Please look at the github sample.  Observe it includes a json.dumps with the data of the event in a callback.  That is called when an event arrives.

Comment: print(tableRowTemplate % (status.time.isoformat(), status.device, status.action + " " + status.clientAddr + " (" + status.reason + ")"))
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found